# It is rude to offer a teacher the study guide you made for their class?

Tags: teaching, interpersonal-issues, lecture-notes

Is it rude to offer my professor a study guide I made for their class? I throughly enjoyed his class but the class he is teaching is extremely hard being it is a premed requirement. I made a study guide for every single chapter with the help of AI, YouTube, and actually reading the chapters. He teaches a lot but sometimes his slides don’t cover to full exam material. The class average is a 50. Id like to see a change in the whole department but I know I’m not the person for that. However, for every chapter I’ve made study guides including drawings and YouTube videos going into deeper explanations of the subjects he is teaching. Would it be rude if I offered it to him to give to future students? I’ve always shared it in our classes group chat and it gets around 60 views, and students tell me it helps them a lot.

Comment: Why do you imagine this would be considered rude?

Comment: Oh god please don't rely on AI for your medical training, that is quite worrying.

Answer (score 6):

Tell them that you've made such a thing and would be happy to share it and their feedback on it would be appreciated. See what develops from that. Perhaps they would like to share it with others, or ask that you not share it. There is more value in creating it than in seeing it, actually.

It doesn't seem like a "big deal".

Answer (score -1):

**It is not rude.**
Any teacher should be happy to see how their students have interacted with the course material.  Not only would it be a valuable resource for the professor, but for future students as well.  You are not presenting this as a recommendation for improving the class, but as a help for others.
As a teacher (high school) for 33 years I always found it at least interesting, if not informative, to see students' notes, study sheets, etc.

It seems you have put a good deal of time into these study guides.  Although it is proper to offer them to your classmates, you might seek a way to monetize them in the future.  Other students might be willing to pay for such a resource.